Understanding the Purpose of Refresh Tokens
I don't understand the purpose of refresh tokens and why they are used when it seems unnecessary.
If the security concern is that access tokens may be stolen, they will become invalid after a while. However, if an access token is stolen, a refresh token can also be stolen alongside it.
If the concern is to check whether a user is active or inactive, this should be verified in every request for security reasons. If a user becomes inactive, they should be immediately logged out in the next request, rather than waiting for the refresh token check to determine the user's active or inactive status.
Could you please clarify the reasons for using refresh tokens, especially in the context of security and user activity management?

Access and refresh token are processed differently and address security risks in a different way in high scalability systems.
Very often, access token is an encrypted session with all permissions the users has. For example, a system may issue an access token as a string with all actions the user may execute; and the system will encrypt the token with a private key.
When a users submits such access token along with a request, the worker (the actual server who processes the request) may verify the access token locally, using a public key. This is a very important feature to be able to make authorization decisions locally - with lots of traffic, one can simply add servers for horizontal scale.
The example from above has an issue - what will happen if the access token is stolen? Since all decisions are made locally on workers, there is no way to revoke the access token.
To address a stolen access token in a distributed scalable system, the access token typically has an expiration date. When the token is expired, the user has to get a new one with a refresh token.
Refresh token is an opportunity to revoke the access. For instance, the user may be asked to re-login.
Access tokens are highly scalable and short lived; Refresh tokens are much less scalable, but are long lived. Combination of both tend to provide more optimal overall solution.
